# Public domain web template/graphics for developers?

Tags: graphics

This is an issue for web developers that aren't or don't have artists.

We would really like some nice templates that we can modify for use on Intranet sites. So does anyone have suggestions for public domain web template/graphics for developers?

Comment: I believe this has been asked before and got closed... but I didn't agree that the original should have been closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite public domain, but if you can cope with a small author's attribution on the web pages, take a look at http://www.freecsstemplates.org. They're licensed under Creative Commons, so you need to leave the attribution in the template, but the attribution is generally quite discreet so most people won't notice it.

Answer (score 3):

Andreas Viklund has great templates that he released into the public domain.

http://andreasviklund.com/templates/

Answer (score 1):

As a designer as a well as a developer i, in unabashed self interest, would say just commission some. Give people some work :-) Then you can reuse and modify them going forward.

Comment: It appears this solution no longer works because, even though the website does offer free templates, you must login to download the templates, and the login functionality no longer works, meaning templates are impossible to download.

Answer (score 1):

[Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). Excellent CSS for an Apple-y look. Grid, responsive design, buttons and now even icons.

Comment: Not quite public domain or am I missing something? Looks Apache 2 licensed.

Comment: [Github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) says MIT license.